# The meaning of 'heir mail'

Tags: meaning

The passage below comes from a book, Hidden Figures by Margot Lee Shetterly: -

> A steady stream of “**heir mail**” announcements ensued. Disability or
>   accumulated sick leave were available to expectant mothers who wanted
>   to return to work when their children were old enough to be left in
>   the care of someone else during the day, though how easily this was
>   done depended on the disposition of their managers.

What's the meaning of “**heir mail**” in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like *heir mail* is being used as a pun, or wordplay on the term *air mail*, meaning a postal service by air freight. The word *heir* is a noun meaning

> a person legally entitled to the property or rank of another on that
>   person's death.

Or more generally, as in this case, a son or daughter. As the 'announcements' mentioned in the passage seem to be about parental leave from the workplace, it looks as though *heir mail* in this context means an announcement of a pregnancy or the intention to have a child, or perhaps announcements about people who will soon be taking parental leave.